# User search didn't find the right emma

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

I thought to connect [this user named 'emma'](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/124113/emma), who I will call Emma #1, with another emma I thought I remembered, so I went to [the user search page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users) and put "emma" in the box.  [It found six](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?search=emma), but none of the six was Emma #1.  Why didn't it find Emma #1?  Are there other emmas that it didn't find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The users page does not show *unregistered* users. ([MSO link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87644/214632).)

[This data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/revision/163301/208139/find-users-by-partial-display-name) may help you find more users, but as the data is only updated one a week that particular user doesn't yet appear.